# Laravel query that append child count field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table **HouseholdProfile** *hasMany* **HouseholdMembers**. I want to query all HouseholdProfile with an addional field of how many members of a the specific profile.

What I want:

```
     ID     Profile     No of Dependents
    1     Greg              3      <--- 3 is Number of child record in member table
    2     Roger             2
```

I have tried the query below but I think it lacks something

```
$query = HouseholdProfile::whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(\DB::raw(count('household_members.id')))
                    ->from('household_members')
                    ->whereRaw('household_members.household_profile_id = household_profiles.id');
            })
        ->where('disaster_risk','like','%1%')->get();
```

Comment: Do you only want profiles that have > 0 children ?

Comment: I want all profiles even if it has no children :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't explicitly need an extra column that contains the child count, then you could eager load the relations:

```
$results = HouseholdProfile::with('household_members')
->where('disaster_risk','like','%1%')
->get();
```

Then you can access the count for each record in your template like so:

```
@foreach($results as $row)
    {{ $row->household_members->count() }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: perfect solution, thanks, i never knew this could be easy